# Css doesn't title fill up all the row

Tags: css, sass

I have in css/sass a title class that looks like this:

```
  .title
    display: block
    float: left
    margin: 25px 10px 25px -20px
    padding: 11px 10px
    font-size: 22px
    font-weight: bold
    letter-spacing: 5px
    color: red
    background: #5279b5
    -webkit-border-radius: 11px
    -moz-border-radius: 11px
    border-radius: 18px
    border-top-left-radius: 0
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0
```

The problem is, I add the title, but for example, if then I add a new form, the form starts right next to the title. I need all the title's row to be empty.

A solution is to use `<br>` after the title but that's not what I want. Any other ideas?

Comment: u've `float:left` property in it.. add `clear:both` also.. or remove `float` property

Comment: removing float property solved the problem partly. Thanks

Comment: @Voila_Voc can you post a demo at jsfiddle.net for us to work?

Comment: Sorry man, i can't . You can try the code yourself. Convert it to css and there it is :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try `clear: both;` or/and `margin-bottom: 10px;`

Comment: Looks like clear: both, doesn't change anything . and the margin-bottom is already 25px . Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I removed `float:left` and added `display: inline-block`, so the background doesn't fill up all the row, only the text part.

**P.S.**: Thanks to all, I'll vote you up when I'll have enough rep.